# Retrieve Facebook Page Insights using backend service

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I wanted to develop nodejs app for my company which runs on certain internal and pull Facebook page's insights(from the page that my company managed via business manager) and store it in database. Subsequently, we will use this insights to present to the management via customized dashboard. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: An app is the basis of using any of the APIs.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the feedback, so the only way to pull the data is by having an app and getting permission for 'read_insights,manage_pages'?

Comment: Yes, that is the way to go.